# how to send different email with the same form?

Tags: php, html, email, email-attachments

i've a form that generates a pdf with fpdf and i want that this form send two different email. one to the client that has compiled the form (like a thank you massage) and a second email to me in order to answer to my client.
I've this code that generates the pdf and send the email to a no-reply mail:

```html
<?php
require('fpdf181/fpdf.php');


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $id_appartamenti = $_POST['id_appartamenti'];
    $taglio = $_POST['taglio'];
    $style = $_POST['style'];
    $piano = $_POST['piano'];
    $mq = $_POST['mq'];
    $mood = $_POST['mood'];
    $finiture = $_POST['finiture'];
    $prezzo = $_POST['prezzo'];
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    
    //A4 width: 219 mm
    //default margin: 10mm each side
    //writable horizontal: 219 - (10*2)=189mm
    $pdf = new FPDF('p', 'mm', 'A4');
    
    $pdf->AddPage();

    //set font to arial, bold, 14pt
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B', 14);

    //cell(width, height, text, border, endline, align)
    
    //titolo
    $pdf->Image('../images/favicon-outline-grigia.png',95, 2, 20, 20,0,1);    
    $pdf->Cell(0,30,'Buongiorno '.$nome.', ecco la configurazione del tuo '.$taglio.' '.$style.':',0,1,'C');
    
    //img
    $pdf->Cell(0,120,'',0,1);
    $pdf->Image('../images/bilocale1.jpg',20, 40, 160, 120,0,1);

    //corpo   
    //set font to arial, reg, 12pt
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','', 10); 

    
    //riga 1
    $pdf->SetFillColor(230,230,230);
    $pdf->Cell(130,8,'ID appartamento:',0,0,'L', true);
    $pdf->Cell(59,8,''.$id_appartamenti.'',0,1,'L', true);//end of line
    
    //riga 2
    $pdf->SetFillColor(255,255,255);
    $pdf->Cell(130,8,'Piano:',0,0,'L', true);
    $pdf->Cell(59,8,''.$piano.'',0,1,'L', true);//end of line
    
    //riga 3
    $pdf->SetFillColor(230,230,230);
    $pdf->Cell(130,8,'Mq:',0,0,'L', true);
    $pdf->Cell(59,8,''.$mq.'',0,1,'L', true);//end of line  
    
    //riga 4
    $pdf->SetFillColor(255,255,255);
    $pdf->Cell(130,8,'Mood:',0,0,'L', true);
    $pdf->Cell(59,8,''.$mood.'',0,1,'L', true);//end of line  
    
    //riga 5
    $pdf->SetFillColor(230,230,230);
    $pdf->Cell(130,8,'Finiture:',0,0,'L', true);
    $pdf->Cell(59,8,''.$finiture.'',0,1,'L', true);//end of line
    
    //riga 5
    //set font to arial, bold, 14pt
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B', 20);    
    $pdf->SetTextColor(234, 103 , 12);
    $pdf->SetFillColor(255,255,255);
    $pdf->Cell(130,50,'',0,0,'R', true);
    $pdf->Cell(59,50,'Totale: '.$prezzo.' Euro',0,1,'R', true);//end of line  
    

    
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////prima mail al cliente
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    
      // email stuff (change data below)
    $to = "$email"; 
    $from = "noreply@tecmasolutions.com"; 
    $subject = "Tecma - la tua configurazione"; 
    $message = "<p>Buongiorno $nome, in allegato potrai trovare le tua configurazione</p>";

    // a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
    $separator = md5(time());

    // carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
    $eol = PHP_EOL;

    // attachment name
    $filename = "$id_appartamenti.pdf";

    // encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
    $pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

    // main header (multipart mandatory)
    $headers = "From: ".$from.$eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol;

    //NOTICE I changed $headers to $body!!

    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
    $body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol; //had one more .$eol

    // message
    $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
    $body .= $message.$eol; //had one more .$eol

    // attachment
    $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
    $body .= $attachment.$eol;
    $body .= "--".$separator."--";
  

  mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);       

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////seconda mail al cliente
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
    
    
       // email stuff (change data below)
    $to2 = "s.zanetti@tecmasolutions.com"; 
    $from2 = "$email"; 
    $subject2 = "Tecma - richiesta info per $id_appartamenti "; 
    $message2 = "<p>Una nuova richiesta da parte di $nome, per l'appartamento $id_appartamenti.</p>";

    // a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
    $separator = md5(time());

    // carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
    $eol = PHP_EOL;

    // attachment name
    $filename = "$id_appartamenti.pdf";

    // encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
    $pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

    // main header (multipart mandatory)
    $headers2 = "From: ".$from.$eol;
    $headers2 .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
    $headers2 .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol;

    //NOTICE I changed $headers to $body!!

    $body2 .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
    $body2 .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol; //had one more .$eol

    // message
    $body2 .= "--".$separator.$eol;
    $body2 .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
    $body2 .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
    $body2 .= $message.$eol; //had one more .$eol

    // attachment
    $body2 .= "--".$separator.$eol;
    $body2 .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;
    $body2 .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
    $body2 .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
    $body2 .= $attachment.$eol;
    $body2 .= "--".$separator."--";   
    
    
 
    
/////////////////////////////////send message
/////////////////////////////////    
/////////////////////////////////    
/////////////////////////////////


    mail($to2, $subject2, $body2, $headers2);
    

}
header('Location: ../thank-you.html');
?>
```

How can i do to send another mail with another body but with the same attachement to another email (like myemail@mydomani.com)?

Comment: Call `mail` function once again.

Comment: Add a cc in your header `$headers .= 'Cc: youremail@yourdomain.com' . "\r\n";`

Comment: Or use bcc in the header `$headers .= 'Bcc: youremail@yourdomain.com' . "\r\n";` if you don't want that the customer see the second eMail Adress.

Comment: If you want to send the same content to another email id then go with CC or BCC
and if you to have different content email content then you mail() again

Comment: You are vulnerable to email injection.

Comment: hi @Progrock, i'm really new on the php and i have to do a big project that i can't really handle. so i ask you a favor if you can help me to be more secure.. thank you

Comment: @StefanoZanetti I can't write the code for you, but read this old article to understand the issues: http://shiflett.org/articles/email-injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call the mail function again with a different $to parameter:

```
$to  = "$email"; 
$to2 = "secondemailaddress@email.com";
// here a lot of your code

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

mail($to2, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: Hi, i've updated my first question, but unfortunately call the mail function again doesn't work...

Comment: @StefanoZanetti Can you send the mail once time? Or do not work the second mail function?

Comment: It works.. I was making a stupid mistake but this solutions is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add simply a second body and execute the mail function

```html
<?php
require('fpdf181/fpdf.php');


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    ...

    // send message NOTICE I replaced "" with $body
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    
    $body2 = 'All you want to add to yourself';

    mail('myemail@mydomani.com', 'Answer required', $body2, $headers);
    

}
header('Location: ../thank-you.html');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by reusing the mail function:

```
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Since the current content of your code is actually the pdf form which means it will be sent to you, then you only need to create the thank you email for the client.

This can be done by creating new variables for the thank you email:

```
$otherto = "someemail@email.com";
$subject2 = "Thank you subject.";
$body2 = "Thank you body";

mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from);
mail ($otherto, $subject2, $body2, $from);
```

Comment: Reading the OP's post, they have a different body for the second email.

Comment: i did not notice that.  will have to rework the code.

Answer (score 0):

My sugestion is to add :

```
$headers .= 'Bcc: youremail@yourmail.com' . "\r\n";;
```

So a hidden copy is sent, and the address is not exposed to the customer.